# What do you call a person who cares about personal well-being, hygiene and fitness?

Tags: word-request, slang, colloquial-language

In colloquial English, what a person who cares about personal well-being, hygiene and fitness, is called? if there are words which refer to just one or two aspects please mention them too.

(Looking for words/expressions that are used in Australian English mainly.)

Comment: Does such a word exist in your langage,  have you used a bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial English, there's one expression that's frequently used. I can't guarantee that Australian English slang doesn't have a better or a more common one

### health nut

- *It used to be that eating yogurt in itself qualified you as a [**health nut**](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Health+nut). Those days are long gone and yogurt is as un-weird as a glass of milk.*
- A [**health nut**](https://www.realfoodforlife.com/are-you-a-health-nut/) is someone who is enthusiastic about nutrition, tries to be on top of the most recent knowledge, BUT realizes that not everyone has the same enthusiasm or beliefs.

Here's a [list of synonyms for health nut](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/health_nut.html), which include the more formal “health conscious person”  and the slightly derogative “gym rat”.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that a person:

> cares about themselves

Or to be more specific, a person practices:

> **healthy/healthful living**

Healthy living is [defined as](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/health-promotion/healthy-living.html):

> With dramatically rising rates of overweight and obesity, “healthy living” needs to become a way of life for more Canadians. **Making healthy food choices, staying physically active and maintaining a healthy weight are essential to good health, and key areas of focus for the Public Health Agency of Canada (PHAC).**